# python3 исключение 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Разбираю исходники одного проекта. Изначально проект написан на python2, мне же нужен код переделанный под python3. Используется библиотека `sqlite3`.

Выдаёт исключение:

> python 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'next'

На следующий код:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(profile, 'data.db')) 
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT item1,item2 FROM metadata WHERE id = 'TEXT';")
row = c.next()
```

Если конкретно, на строку `row  = c.next()`.

Чем заменить эту строку?

Может быть, они используют старую версию библиотеки, когда в новой это делается немного по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Курсор является итератором. В Питоне 3, `.next()` метод для единообразия с другими специальными методами переименован в `.__next__()` используйте `next()` встроенную *функцию*:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> next(db.execute('select 1'))
(1,)
```

Или более специфичные методы для [DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), так как итератор это необязательное расширение DB API—sqlite3 поддерживает, а другие реализации могут и не поддерживать:

```
>>> db.execute('select 1').fetchone()
(1,)
```